# Speeding up this LINQ to SQL code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am developing an ASP.NET where I need to display each purchase for every account in a GridView (so basically each purchase links to an account).

The problem is, we have over 6000 suppliers (granted, these can be filtered down to around 1000 which the customer will usually do), each of whom will have a few transactions. So you can imagine the time it takes to bind this data is very long - in fact, occasionally the SQL server times out. Sadly I cannot use paging, as all the data needs to be displayed in one page.

What I'm doing is similar to the code below (not at my machine so can't copy exactly)

```
IEnumerable<Account> accs = (from s in dc.Accounts select s);
foreach (Account acc in accs)
{
    IEumerable<Purchases> purchs = (from s in dc.Purchases where s.AccountID == acc.ID select s);
    double 30daysval;
    double 60daysval;
    foreach (Purchases purch in Purchases)
    {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - purch.Timestamp;
        if (span.Days <= 30)
        {
            30daysval += purch.Value;
            //Add a row to the grid
        }
        else if (span.Days <= 60)
        {
            60daysval += purch.Value
            //Add a row to the grid
        }
    }
    //Add total row for that account
}
```

Is there a faster way of doing this, perhaps using join's in LINQ or something? I know this may be a bit hopeless seeing as the data involved is huge, and that displaying  a couple of thousands rows on a single page is fairly absurd, but that's what I've been told to do...

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there an FK relationship between Accounts and Purchases? If so, Linq2Sql should make accessing Purchases related to an Account super-easy. If there isn't the relationship, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone who has replied, your suggestions have helped me a lot. One thing I forgot to mention which was a challenge is that they user may want to see accounts with no purchases.

What I did in the end was create my own class, containing an Account object, and a list of Purchase objects. I then do an outer join in LINQ to select each account and their purchases, and store the results into this new class.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assuming that there is no fk keys.  Else you don't need joins.
var Purchases = dc.Accounts
    .Join(dc.Purchases, a => a.Id, p => p.AccountId, (a,p) => new {a,p})
    .Select(p);

double 30daysval;
double 60daysval;
foreach (Purchases purch in Purchases)
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - purch.Timestamp;
    if (span.Days <= 30)
    {
        30daysval += purch.Value;
        //Add a row to the grid
    }
    else if (span.Days <= 60)
    {
        60daysval += purch.Value
        //Add a row to the grid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var resuts =                 (from acc in dc.Accounts
                             join purchase in dc.Purchases on 
                             acc.ID equals purchase.AccountID
                             select new {Account = acc, Purchase = purchase}).ToList();


daysVal30 = results.Where(x=>(DateTime.Now - x.Purchase.Timestamp).Days <= 30).Sum(x=>x.Purchase.Value);
daysVal60 = results.Where(x=>(DateTime.Now - x.Purchase.Timestamp).Days > 30 && (DateTime.Now - x.Purchase.Timestamp).Days <=60).Sum(x=>x.Purchase.Purchase.Value);

grid.DataSource = results;
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile to a SQL query because of the timespan? Linq to Objects, yes, Linq to SQL/Entities, no. If I remember right it will compile but you'll get a runtime exception complaining about store methods because until you execute the query, which then instantiates .Net objects, you can't call .Net methods unless the query provider supports them.

Comment: RichardW1001 notice the ToList at the end of the first query. Second part is executed out of DB.

Comment: My bad, the to list is off the side of the scroll bit and didn't notice it. That will work fine, and fairly quickly, although still not optimal because it's returning and instantiating all results which could be a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: all the results anyway have to be shown in UI, therefore loaded so i think thats not the problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to profile the SQL code that is being sent to the DB.

It is quite possible, that for each account that you query, a new query is being sent to the DB to load your purchases for that account. This is called "deferred loading" or lazy loading. Since you anyway need them all, this is not very efficient.

Assuming that you have the right foreign keys in place, you can use the LoadOptions to make sure only one query is performed.

example:

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Account >(a => a.Purchases );
context.LoadOptions = options;
```

This way, all purchases are directly loaded with the accounts and this might save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The join is the main thing, but an extra thing that'll help - Linq to SQL (and Linq to Entities) won't translate date manipulation into SQL, but they are able to compare a constant date to a value.

At the moment you are looking for (now - timestamp > 30 days) - I suggest you re-arrange that and look for (now - 30 days > timestamp). You need to work out (now - 30 days) in C# because the expression won't translate, but you can then filter your rows at database level before looping through:

```
// Assuming that there is no fk keys.  Else you don't need joins.
var Purchases = dc.Accounts
    .Join(dc.Purchases, a => a.Id, p => p.AccountId, (a,p) => new {a,p})
    .Select(p); //this is not evaluated yet

var todayAnd30 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); //happens instantly in memory
var todayAnd60 = DateTime.Now.AddDaye(60); //happens instantly in memory

var purchases30 = Purchases.Where(p => p.Timestamp > todayAnd30); //will translate to SQL
var purchases60 = Purchases.Where(p => p.Timestamp > todayAnd60; //will translate to SQL

foreach (Purchases purch in purchases30) //purchases30 query hits database at this point
{
   30daysval += purch.Value;
   //any other processing
}

foreach (Purchases purch in purchases60) //purchases60 query hits database at this point
{
   60daysval += purch.Value;
   //any other processing
}
```

Credit to Holystream, I nicked the joins from your answer as a starting point to save typing!